# How do I change the value of child in firebase using a checkbox click

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-realtime-database

This is the code am using to fetch data from my firebase realtime database.

```
private void fetch() {
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("products");

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Product> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Product>()
                        .setQuery(query, new SnapshotParser<Product>() {
                            @NonNull
                            @Override
                            public Product parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                return new Product(snapshot.child("id").getValue().toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("price").getValue().toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("sku").getValue().toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("category").getValue().toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("subCategory").getValue().toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("availability").getValue().toString());

                            }
                        })
                        .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductsViewHolder>(options)  {
            @Override
            public ProductsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.list_product, parent, false);

                return new ProductsViewHolder(view);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(ProductsViewHolder holder, final int position, final Product model) {
                holder.setName(model.getName());
                holder.setPrice(model.getPrice());
                holder.setSubCategory(model.getSubCategory());
                holder.setViewAvailability(model.getAvailability());
                //holder.setSku(model.getSku());
                holder.root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        //Toast.makeText(ProductsActivity.this, model.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

This is the product viewHolder

```
public class ProductsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public CardView root;
    public TextView viewSubCategory;
    public TextView viewName;
    public TextView viewPrice;
    //public TextView viewSku;
    public CheckBox viewAvailability;

    Context context;

    public ProductsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        root = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_product_root);
        viewSubCategory = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewSubCategory);
        viewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewName);
        viewPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewPrice);
        viewAvailability = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewAvailability);
        //viewAvailability.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void setName(String string) {
        viewName.setText(string);
    }

    public void setViewAvailability(String string) {
        if (string.equals("0")){
            viewAvailability.setChecked(false);
        }else {
            viewAvailability.setChecked(true);
        }
    }

    public void setPrice(String string) {
        viewPrice.setText(String.format("%,d", Integer.parseInt(string)));
    }

   /* public void setSku(String string) {
        viewSku.setText(string);
    }*/

    public void setSubCategory(String string) {
        viewSubCategory.setText(string);
    }
}
```

veiwAvailaibility is a checkbox, that when checked it should change the value of availability (which is a child of a product) in firebase from 0 to 1 (checked and unchecked respectively). I am failing to get the clicking checking functionality done in the ViewHolder or in my fetch class. Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void fetch() {
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("products");

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Product> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Product>()
                        .setQuery(query, new SnapshotParser<Product>() {
                            @NonNull
                            @Override
                            public Product parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                return new Product(snapshot.child("id").getValue().toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("price").getValue().toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("sku").getValue().toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("category").getValue().toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("subCategory").getValue().toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("availability").getValue().toString());

                            }
                        })
                        .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductsViewHolder>(options)  {
            @Override
            public ProductsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.list_product, parent, false);

                return new ProductsViewHolder(view);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(ProductsViewHolder holder, final int position, final Product model) {
                holder.setName(model.getName());
                holder.setPrice(model.getPrice());
                holder.setSubCategory(model.getSubCategory());
                holder.setViewAvailability(model.getAvailability());
                holder.viewAvailability.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                        if(isChecked){
                            //suggestion.setSelected(true);
                            DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products").child(model.getId());
                            Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                            updates.put("availability", "1");
                            ref.updateChildren(updates);
                        }else {
                            //suggestion.setSelected(false);
                            DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products").child(model.getId());
                            Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                            updates.put("availability", "0");
                            ref.updateChildren(updates);
                        }
                    }
                });
                //holder.setSku(model.getSku());
                holder.root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: Have you resolved your issue by the additional code in your answer?